# Overwriting variables in coffee script classes and sub classes

Tags: inheritance, coffeescript, default

I'm a Ruby programmer trying to create a small JavaScript library.

As I'm no big JavaScript expert I'm helping myself with CoffeeScript, fighting my way through a rather unknown territory.

The idea:

I want to create several small JavaScript widgets, all of which share some small pieces of functionality.

The shared functionality and config is in the `Base` class. Every widget has its own class that inherits from `Base` and can set its own config (and even overwrite configs of `Base`).

Finally, when a widget is instantiated, it can be passed an option hash, itself overwriting the default options of the widget.

It looks like this so far:

```
@Adg = {}

class Adg.Base
  config =
    debugMessage:   false
    hiddenCssClass: 'visually-hidden'

  # Constructor. Should not be overridden; use @init() instead.
  #
  # - Arg1: The DOM element on which the script should be applied (will be saved as @$el)
  # - Arg2: An optional hash of options which will be merged into the global default config
  constructor: (el, options = {}) ->
    @config = config

    @$el = $(el)

    for key, val of options
      @config[key] = val

    @init()

  # Dummy, must be overridden in inheriting classes.
  init: ->
    throw 'Classes extending App must implement method init()!'

class Adg.Autocomplete extends Adg.Base
  config =
    suggestionsContainer: 'fieldset'
    suggestionsContainerLabel: 'legend'
    alertsContainerId: 'alerts'

  init: ->
    # Merge config into existing one
    for key, val of config
      @config[key] = val
```

This works, but feels clumsy to me:

- I don't like that I have to create default `constructor` that must not be overridden by inheriting classes (I add an `init()` method as a substitute)
- In each inheriting class I have to manually merge the configs

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will do what you are looking for:

```
@Adg = {}

class Adg.Base

  @config =
    debugMessage:   false
    hiddenCssClass: 'visually-hidden'

  constructor: (el, options = {}) ->
    @config = Object.assign {}, Adg.Base.config, options
    @$el = $(el)

class Adg.Autocomplete extends Adg.Base

  @config =
    suggestionsContainer: 'fieldset'
    suggestionsContainerLabel: 'legend'
    alertsContainerId: 'alerts'

  constructor: (el, options={}) ->
    super(el, Object.assign({}, options, Adg.Autocomplete.config))
```

There are a couple changes I made:

1. Using class properties rather than local variables/closure. `@config` on `Adg.Base` is read using `Adg.Base.config`.
2. Using `super` to call the parent constructor from the child's.
3. Using `Object.assign` to merge hashes.

Note that if you're using Coffeescript 2 (uninstall coffee-script and install coffeescript@next package), you can use the spread operator instead of Object.assign:

```
@config = {Adg.Base.config..., config...}`
```